# Actualizar $scope de angular en una funcion de jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Tengo un controlador de angular y necesito que dentro de este vaya una functión jQuery que se encarga de saber si el usuario estuvo inactivo por x segundos.

Aquí les muestro el código que llevo:

```
var modulo = angular.module('appModule',[])
  .controller('nameCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.userlogued = true;
    $.idle(60, function () {
      $scope.userlogued = false;
      alert('Llevas 1 Minuto inactivo');
    });
  });
```

Pero no me actualiza el objeto `$scope`, o sea no lo actualiza como `false` si se cumplieron los 60 segundos.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes poner un link al repo del plugin `$.idle` que estás usando?

Answer (score 3):

Usualmente no debes usar funciones y eventos ajenos a angular a menos que sea absolutamente necesario. La razón de esto es porque entonces debes usar constantemente `$scope.$apply` para que la vista actualize y esto a la vez te puede generar un error

> $apply already in progress

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('DigestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DigestCtrl">
</div>
```

Te puedes encontrar en internet un truco como el siguiente

```
// NO LO USES 
if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
```

No te lo recomiendo y en realidad dicha recomendación viene del propio equipo de angular, lee

[When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

[Antipatrones](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns)

Se puede resumir en esto

> No hagas `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`, esto sólo significa que tu `$scope.$apply()` no está lo suficientemente alto en la pila de ejecución

y

> `$scope.$apply()` debería ocurrir tan cerca del binding del evento asincrónico como sea posible.

Te muestro tu código como sería con `$scope.$apply`

```js
var modulo = angular.module('appModule', [])
  .controller('nameCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.userlogued = true;
    $.idle(20, function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.userlogued = false;
      });
      alert('Llevas 20 segundos inactivo');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="nameCtrl">
  Espere 20 segundos sin actividad 
  <br>
  Usuario logueado: {{userlogued}}
</div>
```

Y la opción recomendada, usar un módulo de angular que haga lo mismo que quieres.

Ejemplo [ng-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle)

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngIdle'])
  .controller('IdleCtrl', function($scope, Idle) {
    $scope.userLogged = true;

    Idle.watch();

    $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
      $scope.userLogged = false;
    });
  })
  .config(function(IdleProvider) {
    IdleProvider.idle(20); // in seconds
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/develop/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IdleCtrl">
  Espere 20 segundos sin actividad 
  <br>
  Usuario logueado {{userLogged}}
</div>
```